# InfluxQL: Calculate periode of status change

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I have a table in my InfluxDB for a parking sensor which sends a state for occupied (1) and vacant (9).
Now I want to create a query which shows me the time period between the status changes so that I can create a report for the time the parkingslot was occupied and free.
The data is generated by the parking sensor and inserted via node-red into the influxdb.
The data is located in InfluxDB version 1.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.
The table data has actually the following structure:

name: parkinginfo
| time | statusnumbered |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1646302488500839186 | 1            |
| 1646302488500203666 | 1            |
| 1646302488499932866 | 2            |
| 1646302488499826263 | 1            |

statusnumbered: 1 = vacant, 2 = occupied

Can someone help me for creating a query for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is feasible to report the total duration for a given state in InfluxDB but only in Flux not InfluxQL (easily).
You could:

1. Enable Flux in v1.8 with the configuration change [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/flux/installation/)
2. Sample Flux could be:

   from(bucket: "yourDatabaseName/autogen") |> range(start: 2022-03-03T00:00:00Z, stop: 2022-03-03T23:59:59Z) |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "yourMeasurementName")  |> stateDuration(fn: (r) => r._value == 1, column: "state", unit: 1m)

   from(bucket: "yourDatabaseName/autogen") |> range(start: 2022-03-03T00:00:00Z, stop: 2022-03-03T23:59:59Z) |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "yourMeasurementName")  |> stateDuration(fn: (r) => r._value == 2, column: "state", unit: 1m)

Again it's still not possible to do it in InfluxQL yet though the community has been waiting for this for a while. See more details [here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/7581).